# Issues with Htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have multiple domains pointing to the same server.

Rather than having them all point to the root directory of the server, I have them each pointing to their own directory on the server.

**I use this HTACCESS code:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    Options +FollowSymLinks

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(www\.)?mycoolwebsite\.(com|org)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cooldir(/.*)?$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$         /cooldir/$1 [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(www\.)?mylolwebsite\.(com|org)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/loldir(/.*)?$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$         /loldir/$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

**My server is set up like this:**

- http://mycoolwebsite.com points to the directory `/cooldir/`
- http://mylolwebsite.com points to the directory `/loldir/`

**So, for exmaple:**

- http://mycoolwebsite.com/cookies/ points to `/cooldir/cookies/`
- http://mylolwebsite.com/pizza/ points to `/loldir/pizza/`

**My problem is, sometimes the URL shows the root directory:**

- http://mycoolwebsite.com/cookies/ sometimes shows up as http://mycoolwebsite.com/cooldir/cookies/
- http://mylolwebsite.com/pizza/ sometimes shows up as http://mylolwebsite.com/loldir/pizza/

How can I fix this?

Note: I do not have access to VirtualHosts. Thas why I am using mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is happening due to `mod_dir` Apache module which is adding a trailing slash in front of directories after `mod_rewrite` rules.

One way to fix it is by using code like this (using `DirectorySlash Off` at top and adding a trailing slash later):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    DirectorySlash Off

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(www\.)?mycoolwebsite\.(com|org)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^((?!cooldir/).*)$ cooldir/$1 [L,NC]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(www\.)?mylolwebsite\.(com|org)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^((?!loldir/).*)$ loldir/$1 [L,NC]

    # add trailing slash in front of directories internally
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L]

</IfModule>
```